# Custom literal method with LiteralConvertible

Tags: swift

I am reading about `LiteralConvertible` protocols (lets take `StringLiteralConvertible` for example), and I found that in swift 1.2 you can use implicit typecasting from literal to your custom `LiteralConvertible` type. Following example taken from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) blog:

```
struct SomeStruct: StringLiteralConvertible {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {}
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {}
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {}
    func someFunc(){}
}
```

Somewhere in executable space:

```
let someStruct: SomeStruct = ""
someStruct.someFunc()                // ok
("" as SomeStruct).someFunc()      // ok
"" is SomeStruct                   // ok (always true warn)
"".someFunc()                      // error: value of type 'String' has no member 'someFunc'
```

Comments are for swift 2 compiler. Seems like there was no error in swift 1.2. Am I missing something or there is no way to achieve this behavior in swift 2?

Comment: It would be weird if the last row (`"".someFunc()`) could resolve to _just any kind of type that happens to conform to `StringLiteralConvertible` and have inst. an function `someFunc {}`_. Protocols cannot know (without explicit testing) which types conform to them, but rather, are used e.g. as type constraint to test if _a given type_ conforms to the protocol. What if we have another type `SomeStruct2: StringLiteralConvertible { ... }` that also implements `someFunc()`, how would the compiler resolve the call `"".someFunc()` if it were to work as you describe above? (->error for Swift>=2)

Comment: @dfri but why it works in swift 1.2?

Comment: Swift 1.2 is ancient in terms of a fast growing (up) language as Swift, so there are bound to be some peculiarities in Swift 1.2 that seems really strange in term of "modern Swift". Just as custom conversion methods (`__conversion()` function), implicit typecasting is a concept that is not entirely agreeable with a statically typed and safe language such as Swift.

Comment: @dfri thank you. I believe that so wide an full information better be as an answer, not as comment.

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense, w.r.t. type safety and non-ambiguity, if the last row (`"".someFunc()`) could resolve to *just any kind of type that happens to conform to StringLiteralConvertible and have instance an function `someFunc {}`*. Protocols cannot know (without explicit testing) which types conform to them, but rather, are used e.g. as type constraint to test if *a given type* conforms to the protocol. What if we have another type `SomeStruct2: StringLiteralConvertible { ... }` that also implements `someFunc()`, how would the compiler resolve the call `"".someFunc()` if the implicit type conversion you describe were to to be allowed?

W.r.t. to the concept working in Swift 1.2: Swift 1.2 is ancient in terms of a fast growing (up) language as Swift, so there are bound to be some peculiarities in Swift 1.2 that seems really strange in term of "modern Swift". Just as custom conversion methods (`__conversion()` function), implicit typecasting is a concept that is not entirely agreeable with a statically typed and safe language such as Swift.

To somewhat base this answer on official sources, we may take a look at Swift evolution proposal SE-0072:

- [SE-0072: Fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions from Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md)

This proposal relates to the implicit bridging between Swift native and Obj-C types, but the *Swift team's position* w.r.t. to any implicit conversions is made quite clear in the description of the [accepted](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-May/000137.html) proposal [**emphasis mine**]

> In Swift 1.2, we attempted to remove all implicit bridging conversions
>   from the language.
>
> ...
>
> In the interest of further simplifying our type system and our user
>   model, we would like to complete this work and fully remove implicit
>   bridging conversions from the language in Swift 3.
>
> ...
>
> I propose that we fully eliminate implicit bridging conversions in
>   Swift 3. This would mean that some users might have to introduce more
>   **explicit casts** in their code, but we would **remove another special case
>   from Swift's type system and be able to further simplify the compiler**.